# Php script with exec function doesn't work into browser but it works if I run it into a terminal with "php5 script_name.php"

Tags: php, exec

my problem:
I wrote Php web page that use exec function and it doesn't work into browser but it works if I run it into a terminal with "php5 script_name.php"... where is the problem?!!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems that server settings prevent the command to be executed. For example, PHP could be running under `www` user, and your command doesn't work under `www` user. Or `exec` function is completely forbidden. Give us some information about your server setup.

Comment: Maybe you could define "doesn't work" too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the command line PHP can use a different php.ini file. Try doing `phpinfo()` and you will see which one each is using.

Comment: where I can see in the page?!

Comment: It's called `Configuration File (php.ini) Path`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problems are that the current working directory is different and/or the `PATH` environment variable is different and/or the file permissions are different. Probably the current working directory (or permissions). Try putting this before your call to `exec()`:

```
chdir($my_directory);
```

Where `$my_directory` is the directory from which you're trying to run it in the CLI.

If you're not getting any errors, try putting this at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

That might give you a better idea of the problem.

Comment: chdir($my_directory); doesn't resolve the problem :S
and 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
doesn't print anything :S